# Como posso fazer cast de uma lista em VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6

Estou começando a programar em **Visual Basic** e preciso fazer `cast` de uma lista de objetos.

Abaixo vai o exemplo de uma classe que contem uma lista de produtos num dos seus atributos.

```
Public Class KnackParsedJSon
    Public total_pages As Integer
    Public current_page As Integer
    Public total_records As Integer
    Public records As New List(Of Product)
End Class
```

Gostaria de armazenar na lista `records` objetos do tipo `Supplier`?

Comment: o seu código é só para Visual Basic 6?

Comment: para todas versões do VB

Comment: Isso está muito incompleto. Poste o código das variáveis, constantes e propriedades da classe `Supplier` e da `Product`